# How do I test for 401 response to a post request in python?

Tags: python, authentication, http-status-code-401

I'm using a post request to access a website that requires authentication. If that authentication is incorrect, I get a Response [401]. I want to test if the authentication is incorrect and if so, abort the process and display an error of some sort. I don't know the syntax to test if the response is 401.

```
output = requests.post(cfg.get('HTTP', 'url'), data = query, verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(credentials['user'], credentials['pass']))

        if output == '<Response [401]>':
            sys.exit('Incorrect Authentication. Please try again.')
        else:
            sys.exit('manual stop1')
```

Instead of `'<Response [401]>'`, I've also tried `'Response [401]'`, `'response [401]'`, `'<Response[401]>'`, `'Response[401]'`, `'response[401]'`, `'[401]'`, `'401'`, and all of those without quotes.

I've seen some responses using flask and json, but I was hoping to not have to change how I'm requesting the data. Thank you!

Comment: Did you consider reading the documentation? http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ - literally the first example shows how to handle HTTP status codes.

Comment: It looks like you're assuming `output` is a string, when it's actually a `Response` class, which is why all your comparisons fail.

Comment: I'm new to python, I didn't realize that the status code was the same thing as the response. Now I know, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You want the `status_code` attribute

```
if output.status_code == 401:
    ...
```

Or to avoid hard coding numbers:

```
if output.status_code == requests.status_codes.codes.UNAUTHORIZED:
    ....
```

Comment: I think it should be `requests.status_codes.codes.UNAUTHORIZED` which is 401, not `METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED` which is 405.